# Using the same cache for two sites

Tags: django, caching, django-johnny-cache

I am hosting two sites from my **Django** code base and I am using **Johnny Cache** for caching.

I have individual settings.py and manage.py for both the sites.

I have configured Johnny Cache for both of them. Now, what is required is that they share the cache. All in all, it is required that if something is changed on Site1, the same should reflect on Site2 (using cache).

I have tried many things like defining the `CACHES`, `CACHE_BACKEND`, `JOHNNY_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX`, `CACHE_PREFIX` settings. But all in vain.

I think I am missing something, but can not figure it out.

**UPDATE**:

The settings:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'johnny.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
        'LOCATION': 'project-default',
        'JOHNNY_CACHE': True
    }
}

CACHE_BACKEND = 'default'
JOHNNY_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX='jc_pc'

CACHE_TIMEOUT = 10000
CACHE_PREFIX = 'pc'
```

Comment: This question isn't really answerable as it stands. What cache backend are you using? What do your settings look like?

Comment: @DominicRodger I have updated the question to reflect what you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the [Local memory cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#local-memory-caching) which means that the cache data is restricted to whatever process is serving your site. If you want to share cache data between different sites, you'll need to use something like [memcached](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#memcached) or [file-system caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#filesystem-caching).